Efficient Mapping of Average Scores Across Interval Windows
I have a df of genomic intervals with millions of rows for example:
chromosome   start  end
1             300   500
1             400   600
...           ...   ... 


find the center of each interval (+/- 250 from the center the start/end)

chromosome   start  end   center
1             300   500   400 
1             400   600   500
...           ...   ... 


Create new windows (-/+ 250 around the center)

chromosome   start  end   center  window_start   window_end
1             300   500   400       50             750
1             400   600   500       150            850
...           ...   ... 



get the scores for every single position within these windows (using my own function). You must first recreate the df with only Chr, window_start, and window_end.

chromosome   start  end  
1             50    750   
1             150   850   
...           ...   ... 




My score function will output the following df (much bigger, there will be 500 rows for each interval because 1 row=1 position. For this example, it would be 1000 rows because we have 2 intervals). :
chromosome   start           end          score
1             50            50            .8       
1             51            51            .2       
1             52            52            .12
...
1             750            750            .43
...           ...   ... 


FINAL: I want a plot such that I will be able to have the x axis represent the position relative to the center (-250th position to +250th position) and the y axis will be the average score. So I would take the -250th position across all of my intervals (here I only have 2 intervals) and I would average across those scores.

Example of what I want is here:

I mostly need help with getting from step 4 to 5 in the most efficient way (step 4 isn't the time-consuming part, step 5 is-- according to the way I'm doing my code right now).
This code here works perfectly, but it is way too slow.
def get_postional_avgs(promoter_df): 
    promoter_df['center'] = (promoter_df['Start'] + promoter_df['End']) // 2

    # Calculate window start and end
    promoter_df['window_start'] = promoter_df['center'] - 250
    promoter_df['window_end'] = promoter_df['center'] + 250
    
    # Prepare a new DataFrame for conservation score requests
    conservation_intervals = promoter_df[['Chromosome', 'window_start', 'window_end']]
    conservation_intervals.columns = ['Chromosome', 'Start', 'End'] #create a new start/end
    
    # Retrieve base-level conservation scores
    base_level_scores = get_base_scores(conservation_intervals)

    # Initialize a DataFrame to hold average scores
    average_scores = []

    for index, row in promoter_df.iterrows():
        center = row['center']
        
        # Extract scores for the current cCRE
        scores_for_cCRE = base_level_scores[
            (base_level_scores['Chromosome'] == row['Chromosome']) &
            (base_level_scores['Start'] >= (center - 250)) &
            (base_level_scores['End'] <= (center + 250))
        ]
        
        # Initialize a list to store average scores for each position
        avg_scores = {}
        
        for pos in range(-250, 251):
            current_position = center + pos
            current_scores = scores_for_cCRE[scores_for_cCRE['Start'] == current_position]
            
            if not current_scores.empty:
                avg_scores[pos] = current_scores['Score'].mean()
            else:
                avg_scores[pos] = np.nan  # Handle missing scores
    
        # Append to the results list
        average_scores.append(avg_scores)

    # Convert average scores to a DataFrame
    avg_score_df = pd.DataFrame(average_scores)


If you want to see the code for the get_score():
import pyBigWig

def get_base_level_conservation_scores(df):
    """
    Retrieve all conservation scores that occur within a given genomic interval.
    The output DataFrame will be expanded to include scores for each base.
    Output DataFrame has 1-indexed coordinates.
    """
    df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
    
    bw = pyBigWig.open("hg38.phyloP100way.bw")

    # Convert to 0-indexing (assuming input is 1-indexed)
    df['Start'] = df['Start'] - 1
    
    # Initialize score data list
    score_data = {
        'Chromosome': [],
        'Start': [],
        'End': [],
        'Score': []
    }
    
    # Process each interval
    for i in range(len(df)):
        chrom = df['Chromosome'][i]
        start = df['Start'][i]
        end = df['End'][i]
    
        # Check for invalid intervals
        if start < 0 or end <= 0 or start >= end:
            print(f"Invalid interval for {chrom}: start={start}, end={end}")
            continue  # Skip this iteration

        # Get scores for the interval
        try:
            scores_per_base = bw.intervals(chrom, start, end)
        except RuntimeError as e:
            print(f"Error for {chrom}: start={start}, end={end} - {e}")
            continue  # Skip this iteration if there's an error

        if scores_per_base is None or len(scores_per_base) == 0:
            # If there are no scores in the specified interval, add NaN entries
            for position in range(start, end):
                score_data['Chromosome'].append(chrom)
                score_data['Start'].append(position)
                score_data['End'].append(position)
                score_data['Score'].append(np.nan)
        else:
            for start_pos, end_pos, score in scores_per_base:
                for position in range(start_pos, end_pos):
                    score_data['Chromosome'].append(chrom)
                    score_data['Start'].append(position)
                    score_data['End'].append(position)
                    score_data['Score'].append(score)

    # Convert to DataFrame, drop duplicates, and drop NaN scores
    score_data_df = pd.DataFrame(score_data)
    score_data_df = score_data_df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Chromosome', 'Start', 'End'])
    score_data_df = score_data_df.dropna(subset=['Score'])
    
    # Close the bigWig file
    bw.close()

    return score_data_df


Isn't (center - 250) the same as row["window_start"]?

Yes, that's how I've defined it.

You do new calculations (center - 250) and (center + 250) every for loop... just use row["window_start"] and row["window_end"] ...which you've already pre-calculated in a far more efficient way.

I made those changes but doesn't change wait time that much @BeRT2me

Suggest you to use parallel_apply (https://github.com/nalepae/pandarallel?tab=readme-ov-file) if working with pandas. Significant speedup.
Sample code is as follows
from pandarallel import pandarallel
pandarallel.initialize(nb_workers=10, progress_bar=True) #set nb_workers based on number of workers you can launch
df = df.parallel_apply(func, axis=1) # func is your custom function on row level


Thank you for your answer. I tried this-- while it did work well for a subset of my data, it crashed when I tried to use my full huge df. You should include in your answer how I can combine this parallelization and chunking or some other method. @Himanshu Sharma
